# How to identify results in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am creating a module that is executing tasks based on a config it receives. These tasks are asynchronous and are returning a promise. Currently there are only two tasks to handle, but if there are more coming up, I will run into a problem of identifying which result of `Promise.all()` belongs to which task.

Here is a snap of my current code:

```
let asyncTasks = [];
let result = {};

if (config.task0) {
    asyncTasks.push(task0(param));
}

if (config.task1) {
    asyncTasks.push(task1(param));
}

Promise.all(asyncTasks)
    .then(results => {

        // TODO: There has to be a prettier way to do this..
        if (config.task0) {
            result.task0 = results[0];
            result.task1 = config.task1 ? results[1] : {};
        } else if (config.task1) {
            result.task0 = {};
            result.task1 = results[0];
        } else {
            result.task0 = {};
            result.task1 = {};
        }

        this.sendResult(result)
    });
```

The config looks like this:

```
const config = {
    task0: true,
    task1: true
};
```

As mentioned in the code, there has to be a prettier and more scaleable way to identify which result is coming from which task, but I can't find anything regarding `Promise.all()` that could help with this.

**How do I identify which value belongs to which promise if `Promise.all()` resolves?**

Comment: You can look into Bluebird, it has handy methods to handle your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no need to use anything other than `Promise.all`. You're experiencing difficulty because the other structure of your program (`config`, and arbitrary link of config key to function) is pretty messy. You might want to consider restructuring the code altogether

```
const config = {
  task0: true,
  task1: true,
  task2: false
}

// tasks share same keys as config variables
const tasks = {
  task0: function(...) { ... },
  task1: function(...) { ... },
  task2: function(...) { ... }
}

// tasks to run per config specification
let asyncTasks = Object.keys(config).map(prop =>
  config[prop] ? tasks[prop] : Promise.resolve(null))

// normal Promise.all call
// map/reduce results to a single object
Promise.all(asyncTasks)
  .then(results => {
    return Object.keys(config).reduce((acc, task, i) => {
      if (config[task])
        return Object.assign(acc, { [prop]: results[i] })
      else
        return Object.assign(acc, { [prop]: {} })
    }, {})
  })

// => Promise({
//      task0: <task0 result>,
//      task1: <task1 result>,
//      task2: {}
//    })
```

Note: we can depend on the order of `results` because we used `Object.keys(config)` to create the input array of promises and `Object.keys(config)` again to create the output object.

Comment: Accepted this now as it is an actual solution that does not require any other libraries. This is more like something I had in mind when thinking "There has to be a prettier way", thank you for the insight

Answer (score 11):

`Promise.all` resolves with an array of values, where each value's index in the array is the same as the index of the Promise in the original array passed to `Promise.all` that generated that value.

If you need anything more fancy you'll need to keep track of it yourself or use another library that offers such functionality (like Bluebird).

Comment: bluebird's `Promise.join()` is the way to go as I see, gonna accept the answer when I am able to :)